# How to automatically run `npm run dev` for React vite app running in Docker

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have a Vite React app with a Flask API running in Docker with WSL 2 through docker-compose. But now I have to manually run these commands to be able to access my React app in the browser:

```
docker exec -it vite_docker sh
npm i && npm run dev
```

Where can I put these commands so they're run automatically while the docker-compose is doing it's thing?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vite_react:
    image: node:alpine
    container_name: vite_react
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /srv/app
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./ML-Flask-React
        target: /srv/app
    tty: true

  flask_app:
    build: ./ML-Flask-API
    container_name: flask_app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
```

Dockerfile Flask:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

The React app doesn't have a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reasonably typical to build your own Docker image to...

1. Install dependencies
2. Execute the appropriate commands when starting

For example

```docker
# ML-Flask-React/Dockerfile.development

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Then use this in your Compose service

```yaml
services:
  vite_react:
    build:
      context: ./ML-Flask-React
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./ML-Flask-React:/srv/app
      - /srv/app/node_modules
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46166304/283366) in regards to the anonymous `/srv/app/node_modules` volume mount.

I've named the file `Dockerfile.development` as you very probably have a production build `Dockerfile` which you won't want to use for running the dev server

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `ENTRYPOINT npm run dev` at the end of your Docker file. This will work as the primary function or command of your application. It will be executed whenever your Docker image is executed.

You can learn more about this at [ENTRYPOINT](https://kinsta.com/blog/dockerfile-entrypoint/#:%7E:text=ENTRYPOINT%20is%20an%20essential%20tool,for%20more%20flexible%20container%20behavior.)